# Why won't Sylpheed send or receive?

Tags: tag, email-client, sylpheed

I have just installed Sylpheed but it neither receives nor sends emails.

1. I selected IMAP and clicked Forward.
2. Entered my email address ‘youruser@riseup.net’.
3. Give the account a name and clicked Forward.
4. Filled in ‘youruser’ and ‘yourpassword’ and mail.riseup.net (for both incoming and outgoing servers). 5. Select SSL/TLS for both.
5. Select Use SMTP Authentication. And clicked Forward. Got the email server – but not able to receive or send???

What do I need to do?

Comment: Hi, we need more detail to help you, such as what type of account you have setup, error message, steps to reproduce. Please remember hide private info such as emails/passwords.

Comment: Right NGRhodes Be patient I am 77 & recovering from sugery.

Comment: Starting again!   1. I selected IMAP  and clicked Forward. 
2. Entered my email address ‘youruser@riseup.net’. 
3. Give the account a name  and clicked Forward. 
4. Filled in ‘youruser’ and ‘yourpassword’ and mail.riseup.net (for both incoming and outgoing servers). 
5. Select SSL/TLS for both. 
6. Select Use SMTP Authentication. And clicked Forward. 
Got the email server – but not able to receive or send??? Please help

Comment: Victor, Thanks - I have updated your question with the extra details.